# "Unable to Run Nodemon: Execution Policy Error in PowerShell"

Tags: powershell, scripting, nodemon

I have installed nodemon on my system, but when I try to run it, I encounter the following error:

```
nodemon : File C:\Users\stunn\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ nodemon server1.js
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

It seems to be related to the execution policy in PowerShell. I tried to change the execution policy to allow script execution, but it didn't resolve the issue. How can I fix this problem and get nodemon to work?

I appreciate any guidance or suggestions to help resolve this execution policy error. Thank you!

Comment: What exactly did you do to change the execution policy?